# How to set a view of a Microsoft List as the default view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, microsoft-lists

Before SharePoint List became Microsoft list I could set a certain view as the default view.

I have 3 views called: "Rooster", "Overview" and "Vandaag". How can
I set the view "Rooster" as the default view?

And how can I see that the view "Rooster" is the default view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to set list view as the default view:

1. Go to SharePoint list & open "Rooster" view
2. Click on **Switch view options** dropdown at the top right corner.
3. Select **Set current view as default**.

[image]

---

**Solution 2** - From classic view settings:

1. Click on **Switch view options** dropdown at the top right corner.
2. Select **Edit current view**.
3. Check **Make this the default view** checkbox
4. Click **OK**

[image]

---

**Note**:

You can only make the **public view** as the default view. If your view is **private view**, this will not work.

---

**How to check the current default view**:

1. Go to your list
2. Click on Settings (Gear) icon at the top right corner
3. Click on **List settings**
4. On list settings page, scroll down to the **Views** section
5. Under Views section, you can see the current default view like below:

[image]

Comment: Also, you will need **Edit** (or higher) permissions on the SharePoint list to perform this operation.